# Reusing part of already selected SQL query result - aka do not repeat itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have perfectly working SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    Product.ID 
FROM 
    Product WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE 
    Product.Type = 1 AND Product.No = '123456789'

UNION 

SELECT 
    Description.ID 
FROM 
    Description WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE 
    Description.Opis LIKE '%hello%'
    AND Description.ID IN (SELECT Product.ID 
                           FROM Product WITH(NOLOCK) 
                           WHERE Product.Type = 1)
```

but I am worried about repeating following

```
SELECT Product.ID 
FROM Product WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE Product.Type = 12
```

Is there a way to query for it once and reuse it in those 2 places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a common table expression (cte):

```
with cte as (
SELECT Product.ID, Product.No 
FROM Product WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE Product.Type = 1
)
SELECT ID
FROM cte
WHERE No = '123456789'

UNION

SELECT Description.ID
FROM Description WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE Description.Opis LIKE '%hello%'
  AND Description.ID IN (SELECT ID from cte)
```

BTW, maybe you want UNION ALL instead of UNION? (Should duplicate rows be kept or removed?)

Comment: Dupes should be removed but I do at the end `GROUP BY ID` - got better solution?

Comment: I wasn't aware of a the GROUP BY. But I suppose you want UNION ALL, to have all rows from the two selects returned.

Comment: CTE makes a query easier to read for the programmer, but SQL Server would inline it. You can compare execution plans for query without CTE and with CTE. In this example they should be the same.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to also use table variables. Also added join in the second part of `UNION`:

```
DECLARE @ProductTemp TABLE (Id int, No int)

INSERT INTO @ProductTemp
SELECT Product.Id, Product.No
FROM Product WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE Product.Type = 1

SELECT ID 
FROM @ProductTemp
WHERE No = '123456789'
UNION 
SELECT Description.ID
FROM Description WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN @ProductTemp AS p ON Description.ID = p.ID
WHERE Description.Opis LIKE '%hello%'
```